# Ajax feedback from newsletter

Tags: ajax, html-email

I have created email contents as an html page.
I have placed 4 check boxes and every time one of them is checked I want to run ajax which calls a url with parameters. Is such a thing possible or the email client will not run it for security reasons or/and other reasons?
I can do it with a link to a page with the same contents but the recipient may not bother to click the link.
The whole idea is: Can we run ajax calls in html email contents as if the contents were in an autonomous web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. All JavaScript is stripped from emails for security reasons. The best you can do, as you've listed, is to have a link in the email with parameters to allow the landing page to do it.

You can achieve interactivity, however, with checkboxes - such as hiding/showing content (already placed in emails). If you're already inserting the parameters, I'm assuming then you have the information--so place that content hidden in the email, which when checked, shows. Mark Robbins shows how it's done: https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/10/punched-card-coding-the-secret-of-interactive-email/ (if that's what you wanted, let us know in the comments and/or include your code and we can give a tailored example)

Comment: Thank you. Yes I can't. There are workarounds, like you have suggested, but there is not 100 % compatibility with all email clients. It is safer with a link to a landing page